# Android Application convert required permissions to features

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions

I have just uploaded my new Android application to `Google Play store` and found that my simple application is unsupported to 909 devices.

```
Required permissions are 

android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.CALL_PHONE
android.permission.INTERNET
```

Now i want to make CALL_PHONE and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION optional. 
Means I want to check pragmatically if a device can't make call or can't provide fine location information.

By doing so i think i can support more devices.

Comment: you can make you app available to more devices, its the other way around you cant do i think

Comment: You can't, as far as I am aware. I think you just have to make two versions of your app.

Comment: @KenY-N , While googling i found many results saying that change uses-permission to uses-feature. So i thought removing required features and adding programming check will make it available to more devices. Am i right?

Comment: @JRowan, can you please explain what do you mean?

Comment: i just know that once you make app available to devices that app always has to be available to those devices, im not sure about changing it to be available to more devices, i dont think it should be a problem though because more devices still includes the original devices, im not 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Features include APIs for:

```
Camera functions
Location data (GPS)
Bluetooth functions
Telephony functions
SMS/MMS functions
Network/data connections
```

For feature requirements declared in `<uses-feature>` elements, Google Play assumes that those are required by the application & would filter based on those.

If an application attempts to use any of the features without declaring in the application's manifest, a security exception would be thrown back to the application.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry It is not possible whether you write code to check device is supporting some features or not. Because you have to declare all the permissions required for the App.

FYI, Play store filters based on the permissions declared inside the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: While googling i found many results saying that change uses-permission to uses-feature. So i thought removing required features and adding programming check will make it available to more devices. Am i right?

Comment: uses-feature applies to features like Bluetooth, camera.  Not applicable in your case.